# Angular templates in WebStorm 2020.3 show Unresolved pipes and variables after recent updates

Tags: angular, webstorm

We recently upgraded to Angular 12 and `"typescript": "4.2.4"`. I use WebStorm 2020.3.

My template files suddenly fail to recognize pipes such as `date` or `async` and `public` component properties (that were previously recognized and I'm not the only member of my team impacted this way). But, the app compiles without issues.

This is my first time asking a question here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

package.json dependencies:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/upgrade": "12.0.5",
    "@cnvr/alerts": "2.5.0",
    "@cnvr/common": "0.6.0",
    "@cnvr/cuik": "4.26.0",
    "@cnvr/global-search": "4.2.0",
    "@iamadamjowett/angular-click-outside": "2.10.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "10.0.0",
    "ajv": "6.12.5",
    "ajv-keywords": "3.5.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "1.2.4",
    "cypress-plugin-tab": "1.0.5",
    "cypress-real-events": "1.3.0",
    "cypress-xpath": "1.6.1",
    "d3": "5.8.0",
    "d3-format": "3.0.1",
    "deep-diff": "1.0.2",
    "deep-equal": "1.0.1",
    "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
    "istanbul": "0.4.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.1",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "latest": "0.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "luxon": "1.26.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.12",
    "node-sass-asset-functions": "0.1.0",
    "npm": "6.14.11",
    "pako": "1.0.11",
    "pluralize": "7.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "qrcode": "1.4.4",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.8",
    "source-map-explorer": "1.8.0",
    "ts-deepcopy": "0.1.4",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.5",
    "@cypress/skip-test": "2.6.0",
    "@types/d3": "5.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "12.12.31",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.23.0",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.27.1",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "5.3.0",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "cypress": "7.0.0",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "1.5.0",
    "dateformat": "1.0.12",
    "debug": "4.1.1",
    "del": "1.2.1",
    "eslint": "7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "35.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "fs-extra": "10.0.0",
    "glob": "7.1.5",
    "install": "0.4.4",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "2.2.1",
    "junit-report-merger": "2.2.2",
    "karma": "6.3.4",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chai-sinon": "0.1.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.2",
    "karma-growl-reporter": "0.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.0",
    "karma-mocha": "0.2.2",
    "karma-parallel": "0.3.1",
    "karma-sinon": "1.0.5",
    "method-override": "2.3.10",
    "minimist": "1.2.5",
    "mocha": "2.5.3",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "morgan": "1.9.1",
    "node-fetch": "2.6.1",
    "node-notifier": "4.6.1",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "plato": "1.7.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "q": "1.4.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "rxjs-marbles": "6.0.1",
    "serve-favicon": "2.5.0",
    "sinon": "1.15.4",
    "sinon-chai": "2.14.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.2.4",
    "wiredep": "2.2.2",
    "yargs": "13.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: Here too with webstorm. Also the router-outlet was not recognised : Component or directive matching router-outlet element is out of the current Angular module's scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to webstorm 2021.1.3 did resolve this for me

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by running `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` on my project file in the terminal.

Comment: This was a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had this problem too, but it was resolved with this setup

Comment: i have a different option for that. i turned it on, but still seeing broken pipes. did you have to restart webstorm?

Comment: I solved it like this, and then restarted the editor

Comment: Thanks for continuing the conversation. Restarting WebStorm didn't do it for me.

Comment: Or change the version to see, I use 2021.1.3

Comment: restarting didn't do this for me too

Comment: If you don't give me the thumbs up, I would have answered it already. Just update the version. It's a bit bug